# GCP - Apply IAM role to Service account to prevent deletion of files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, service-accounts, google-iam

I have a GCP Service account for a project that uses the Google Sheets and Google Drive API. The service account can currently create files, move them, update them, delete them, etc. But I want to apply a role that prevents the service account from ever deleting a file or moving files that this service account did not explicitly create. I have looked at specific permissions for a new role, but found nothing that explicitly concerns Google Sheets API or Google Drive API. I thought I'd be able to have an IAM policy like this:

```
{
  "permissions":["sheets.spreadsheets.create", "sheets.spreadsheets.values.update"]
}
```

I'm not claiming it should be this simple, just thought it could be as refined as this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the information provided creating an IAM custom role would be the best path. By creating your own role, you can modify the scopes and limitations of the permissions for your service account. Just a reminder that you cannot make a custom role at a folder level. Attached is the documentation for more information and details.[1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating

Comment: The question is how to actually apply these types of limitations with a role -- not just what a role is. The problem is that the custom roles have no apparent customization for things like Google Drive and Google Sheets api.